# UIImageView displayed in wrong UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a `UITableViewCell` that contains two `UIImageView` (`imgView1` and `imgView2`), based on the data source I have to hide `imgView2`. It works correctly, expect one thing. In those cases when I need to hide `imgView2` and I have a lot of cells `imgView2` will be displayed after scrolling to the bottom. I'm hiding `imgView2` programmatically when it's needed so I don't understand what causes this issue. Is it possible to fix this? Or I should create another custom cell class to separate the two layout?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

  NSString *contentCreator = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", object[@"contentCreator"]];

MDTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if ([contentCreator isEqualToString:[PFUser currentUser].objectId]) {

    cell.usernameLabl.text = object[@"username"];

    PFFile *avatar1 = [Helper currentUserPhoto];
    cell.imageView2.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView2.frame.size.width / 2;
    cell.imageView2.clipsToBounds = YES;
    cell.imageView2.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    cell.imageView2.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    cell.imageView2.file = senderAvatar;
    [cell.imageView2 loadInBackground];


    PFQuery *queryAvatar = [PFUser query];
    queryAvatar.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    [queryAvatar whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:object[@"recipientUser"]];
    [queryAvatar getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

        if (object) {
            PFFile *avatar2 = [object objectForKey:@"profilePhoto"];
            cell.imageView1.layer.cornerRadius = cellMessage.imageView1.frame.size.width / 2;
            cell.imageView1.clipsToBounds = YES;
            cell.imageView1.file = senderAvatar;

            [cell.imageView1 loadInBackground];
        }
    }];
}

else {

    cell.imageView2.hidden = YES;
    cell.usernameLabl.text = object[@"usernameSender"];

    PFQuery *queryAvatar2 = [PFUser query];
    queryAvatar2.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    [queryAvatar2 whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:object[@"senderUser"]];
    [queryAvatar2 getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

        if (object) {

            PFFile *senderAvatar = [object objectForKey:@"profilePhoto"];
            cell.imageView1.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView1.frame.size.width / 2;
            cell.imageView1.clipsToBounds = YES;
            cell.imageView1.file = senderAvatar;

            [cell.imageView1 loadInBackground];

        }
    }];


}
return cellMessage;

}
```

Comment: From where you are getting contentCreator value?
you haven't checked the objectAtIndexPath. Now when "contentCreator" will change?

Comment: Now its fine, pls try to unhide the imageView2 as ShahiM suggested.
You can unhide it in if condition.

Comment: @Samir ShahiM's answer is correct. I'm just curious, do you think it would be better to  create a plus cell class to handle it without if statement?

Comment: First of all I haven't seen your view. Secondly, creating separate cell is helpful(and recommended) when you have totally different cell design, Like Textfield, switch, slider etc.

Comment: @Samir it's the same design, except a plus image view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its a glitch caused by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. suppose u hide `imageView2` for cell `x`, and you scroll down, the cell used for x will be reused for another cell 'y', so in cell y, `imageView2` is still hidden due to your code for cell x.

So the best way is to unhide `imageView2` at the beginning of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object 
{

  MDTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

  cell.imageView2.hidden = NO;

  //rest of your code...
```

Comment: It seems it's working, ShahiM thank you very much. Just another question, do you think it would be better to create another cell class and handle the two situation differently?

Comment: different cell subclasses is the proper approach. but if you only have some minor variations between the cells, then its not worth the trouble, your method does just fine.

Answer (score 2):

What's your complete code for using dequeueReusableCell and incase if it's nil while dequeuing allocating it?

It might happen that when cell are more for first/ visible table frame's cell dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: returns nil and the cell is allocated with imageView2 shown and while scrolling if dequeue cell is reused than it will show imageView2.

Comment: That's all, I'm not handling when it's nil. How should I do that?

Comment: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: always returns non-nil cell